# Finding the maximum value in a group with differentiation

Tags: python, pandas, max, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

| index | ID | value_1 | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 200 | 126 |
| 1 | 1 | 200 | 127 |
| 2 | 1 | 200 | 128.1 |
| 3 | 1 | 200 | 125.7 |
| 4 | 2 | 300.1 | 85 |
| 5 | 2 | 289.4 | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | 0 | 76.9 |
| 7 | 2 | 199.7 | 0 |

My aim is to find all rows in each `ID`-group (1,2 in this example) which have the max value for `value_1` column. The second condition is if there are multiple maximum values per group, the row where the value in column `value_2` is maximum should be taken.

So the target table should look like this:

| index | ID | value_1 | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 200 | 128.1 |
| 1 | 2 | 300.1 | 85 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by all 3 columns and then [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = (df.sort_values(['ID', 'value_1', 'value_2'], ascending=[True, False, False])
         .drop_duplicates('ID'))
print (df1)
   ID  value_1  value_2
2   1    200.0    128.1
4   2    300.1     85.0
```

Comment: I have another question: is there a possibility to calculate the mean value of ```value_1``` and ```value_2``` (without 0-values) within an ```ID```-group?

Comment: @Horst-Jackson - Do you think `df = df.set_index('ID').replace(0, np.nan).mean(level=0)` ?

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I'm searching for!